# SSRS Nested IIF using different fields to change font color

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report where I need to accomplish 2 tasks:

```
=IIf(Fields!TargetVOC.Value = "","White","Black")

=IIf(Fields!VOCFlag.Value=1,"Green","Red")
```

I need to combine #1 and #2 in one expression. (see below)

My Expression

```
=iif(Fields!TargetVOC.Value="","White",iif(Fields!VOCFlag.Value=1,"Green","Red"))
```

When the report renders, I'm loosing the 2nd IIF statement to turn the font color to either Green or Red if VOCFlag=1.  What I need it to happen is to evaluate the first IIF expression that if the TargetVOC is null or blank it hides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you alter the first iif to using IsNothing, for example:

=iif(IsNothing(Fields!TargetVOC.Value),"White",iif(Fields!VOCFlag.Value=1,"Green","Red"))